# How to override the default behavior of SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler in Spark client?

Tags: apache-spark

The docs for [SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/util/SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler.html) indicate the following:

> The default uncaught exception handler for Executors terminates the
>   whole process, to avoid getting into a bad state indefinitely. Since
>   Executors are relatively lightweight, it's better to fail fast when
>   things go wrong.

Is it possible to override this behavior?

Alternatively, is there a better way to determine that Spark is unavailable before getting into a situation where the SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler is invoked?

My scenario is that I am running tests in an environment where Spark may or may not be available.  If Spark is available, I want to run the tests.  If not, I want to skip them.

I am trying something like this right now:

```
object SparkUtility {
  def Conf(url: String, app: String): SparkConf =
    new SparkConf().setMaster(url).setAppName(app)

  def Connect(conf: SparkConf): Try[SparkContext] =
    Try(new SparkContext(conf))
}

class SampleTestSpec extends FlatSpec  {

  SparkUtility.Connect(SparkUtility.Conf("spark://HOST:7077", "appname")) match {
    case Success(sc) => runAllTests(sc)
    case Failure(f) => runOfflineTests()
  }

  // ...
}
```

Unfortunately when Spark is offline the Failure case is never matched and the application terminates with the following (client side):

```
16/01/05 13:35:20 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@BADHOST:7077] has failed, address is now gated for
[5000] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@BADHOST:7077]] Caused by: [Connection refused: no further information: BADHOST/127.0.0.1:7077]
16/01/05 13:35:39 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://BADHOST:7077...
16/01/05 13:35:39 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[appclient-registration-retry-thread,5,main]
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@4ae4230 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4c7b5fb6[Run
ning, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 3]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2048)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:821)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1372)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:110)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anonfun$tryRegisterAllMasters$1.apply(AppClient.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anonfun$tryRegisterAllMasters$1.apply(AppClient.scala:95)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint.tryRegisterAllMasters(AppClient.scala:95)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint.org$apache$spark$deploy$client$AppClient$ClientEndpoint$$registerWithMaster(AppClient.scala:1
21)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AppClient.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrExit(Utils.scala:1119)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anon$2.run(AppClient.scala:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/01/05 13:35:39 INFO DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
16/01/05 13:35:39 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/01/05 13:35:39 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory ...
16/01/05 13:35:39 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory ...
16/01/05 13:35:39 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory ...
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better to simply use tags or properties to switch between off-line and all?

Comment: That's what I'm doing for now.  Ideally I'd like something that "just worked" depending on the environment - but I'd also prefer that (in this limited case) the application did not terminate, but rather bubbled the exception up to the caller so that the tests could continue.

Comment: It turns out for unit testing there is a way to run Spark in the test process - by using "local[*]" as the master Spark URL, everything will start and execute in-process which is actually the better scenario for me.  So while this does resolve my specific need I'm going to leave the question open as-is because I think that the general issue of "Can I change the default behavior" is still interesting (especially since the docs call the behavior the "default" indicating that there are other behaviors possible).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but one thing you can do is to try and open a TCP connection to the master. Success is no guarantee that you will be able to connect, but if this fails, then the master is definitely not available.

```
import java.net._

object SparkAvailabilityCheck {
  // Probes the master by opening a socket. If that fails, the master is
  // definitely not available at the given location, though non-failure is
  // no guarantee that creating a SparkContext will succeed.
  def isSparkOnline(masterLocation: URI): Boolean = {
    try {
      val host = InetAddress.getByName(masterLocation.getHost)
      val socket = new Socket(host, masterLocation.getPort)
      socket.close()
      true
    } catch {
      case ex: ConnectException => false
    }
  }
}
```